# Python subprocess doesn't find the PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, django, subprocess, pythonpath

I'm using subprocess to call a python script but it doesn't work because it doesn't find my `PYTHONPATH`. I have a my `PYTHONPATH` put and it goes inside my folder.
let's say my `PYTHONPATH` contains this path: `/home/myproject`.
My architecture is this one: `/myproject/djangoView/view_x.py`
from my `view_x.py` I use subprocess to launch a script that is on `/myproject/scripts/script.py`

Then I start my server django, I have to click on a button and it should launch my `script.py`, to be clear it does work in local, but it doesn't work in preprod which is a server ubuntu.
The error I have is `ModuleNotFound` because in my script I call `/utils/utils.py`

So I just don't really understand why I have an error, my `PYTHONPATH` is set and correct, all the imports calling `/utils/utils.py` are working except when I'm using subprocess in my preprod server. I can't reproduce it in local.
Is someone have an explanation for this behavior ?

Here is my call:

```
subprocess.run(["nohup python3 /home/myproject/scripts/script.py &"], shell=True)
```

Thanx.

Comment: The `subprocess` call has several syntax problems but your problem description sounds like Django is being run by a web server (nginx?) which does not expose this variable. Please [edit] to provide enough debugging details; see also the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: I change the subprocess call multiple time, without [], or with it but separating each commands, etc... This one "works" because it calls my script in the right folder, the problem comes because of the subprocess or after it because I don't have my PYTHONPATH. I can't give you more information because I don't know what cause this behavior.

Comment: The first argument should simply be a string with `shell=True`, take out the `[...]` and probably the `&` which doesn't make sense for a subprocess anyway. If you really want it to run in the background, use `Popen` instead of `run`.

Comment: Perhaps a better solution for running some Python code in a separate process is to use `multiprocessing`; then the subprocess should inherit these things from the host Python process (I hope ...). Still, the real solution for your actual question is probably to tweak your Nginx configuration.